# How to support RDP on to VMs in a Hub and Spoke toplogy using AAD authentication (and CAP)

Tags: azure, rdp, entra-id

I have a hub and spoke topologogy made up of a central vnet and then peered VNETs. Inside each peered VNET is a VM.

I want to allow RDP access to the VM (which is AAD joined) via AAD authentication. AAD auth needs to be restricted via CAP.

This, it turns out, may be tricky.

**Option 1:**
I had hoped to place an Azure load balancer inside the hub and assign a single IP address to it. In my AAD I would the add a CAP for this IP. This would then allow me to RDP (via a jump box in the hub) onto each spoke VM.

Alas Azure load balancer doesnt support peered VNETs.

**Option 2:**
I considered using Bastion to access the VNets... but bastion doesnt support AAD or peered networks. So thats useless.

**Option 3:**
I could stick a public IP on each VM (and allow only outbound traffic via an NSG) with all public IPs using a prefix to simplify CAP. Although this rather confusing article https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-resource-manager/management/azure-subscription-service-limits?toc=/azure/virtual-network/toc.json#networking-limits seems to imply that the number of public ips is restricted per subscription (to 10 for basic!?!)
Here I'd use IP prefixes to simplify CAP to a known range.

**Option 4:**
I could introduce a virtual appliance.
This sounds horrid and requires management etc

Are there other options Ive missed (I almost certainly have)?

Comment: Bastion would be the way to go, access to which you can protect with RADIUS and NPS extension for Azure.
https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/authentication/howto-mfa-nps-extension
With Azure authentication, you can get Conditional Access as well. You can also protect RDP with MFA.

Comment: Bastion doesnt support peered networks (my topology is hub and spoke). You need a Bastion instance for every VNET which is prohibitively expensive

Comment: Also, unless Im reading this wrong (I might be) AAD isnt supported https://feedback.azure.com/forums/217313-networking/suggestions/37961281-aad-integration